# Python - Read msgpack file and store it to the Data Frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, msgpack

```
def df_to_msgpack(df, filename):
df.to_msgpack(filename, default=decimal_default)
```

The function above stores the DF to messagepack file. Now, I want to read the file and store it in the DF for further calculation. How can it be done?

```
    with open(filename, 'rb') as data_file:
    data_loaded = msgpack.unpackb(data_file.read())
```

I tried the solution above and it didn't help.

```
msgpack_read(filename)
```

The solution also only reads the file. Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pandas.read_msgpack` although it still is an [experimental version](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_msgpack.html) in `ver0.23.4`.

```
df = pd.read_msgpack(filename)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the accepted [answer from gyoza](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51997134/18059269) is outdated (link is dead, pandas read_msgpack is [removed since v1.0.0](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v1.0.0.html?highlight=read_msgpack#removal-of-prior-version-deprecations-changes)) but still ranked high on google, here's an updated solution:

```py
import msgpack
import pandas as pd

with open(filename, "rb") as file:
    data_bytes = file.read()
data = msgpack.unpackb(dataBytes)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

The file, which is localized via the path "filename", is read as bytes. The bytes are decoded by messagepack and the result can be converted directly into a pandas dataframe.

Note that the data loaded by messagepack must correspond to the [pandas data structure](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html?) or it must be adjusted accordingly before being converted to a dataframe.